# How to differ URL change manually and programmatically in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

so the question is in the title. I need to differ navigation by clicking button with `[routerLink]` and when user enter URL manually in browser search bar.

**UPD:** So i have page with fixed menu. This menu looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li [routerLink]="[/step1]">Step1</li>
  <li [routerLink]="[/step2]">Step2</li>
  <li [routerLink]="[/step3]">Step3</li>
</ul>
```

Every step has own content that is rendered under the menu in `<router-outlet>`.
The order of steps is important. So i want to redirect the user from '/step2' to '/step1' if he entered url manually in the browser like `www.my-app.com/step2`. And if he got to the `step2` from the menu - do not redirect.

Comment: Why you want to do so? can you please explain bit more on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve, what you probably want using Angular's [**ActivatedRoute**](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#activatedroute) class.

Import and inject the provider:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'

// ...

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { ... }
```

Then subscribe to it and test it:

```
this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(url => console.log(url))
```

---

[**More on Angular's Router events**](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events)

Comment: I tried it, but i got the same console.log result in both cases. I need to differ routing by `Router` and by entering url in the browser. I know that in case of entering url in the browser the page is reloading and in the `Router` case - not. I need to differ it

Comment: Can you update your question above and paste a small, but concise version of your code, so we can help you a bit better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible without having a variable to check against to see where the user has come from.

You could pass a parameter on the button click and then check for that parameter value on the second page. It could look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li [routerLink]="[/step1]">Step1</li>
  <li [routerLink]="[/step2]" [queryParams]="{completeStepOne: true}">Step2</li>
  <li [routerLink]="[/step3]">Step3</li>
</ul>
```

Then in the init method of your step 2 component get that param and check against it:

```
const params = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
this.completeStepOne = params.queryParams.completeStepOne;

if (!this.completeStepOne) {
    this.router.navigate(['step1']; // If it is not true, return user to step one
}
```

Alternatively you could have all steps within the same page if your app design allows and handle the user journey in the one component. Angular material has a good stepper design with configuration that allows you to stop the user from jumping to the second step without first doing something on the first step. You can view the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).